# SQL Server - Set Canadian Business Holiday Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Note: this is for Canadian Holidays:

I need to populate a table with Canadian business holidays.
I have the following query that sets up business holiday dates and also considers the movement of the holiday to the next weekday in the event of the holiday occurring on a weekend.  ie if the holiday occurs on Sunday then Monday becomes a holiday.  I also identify weekdays with a flag and add an English description of the day.

I add a few calculated columns to make the job a bit easier, these are removed again after all the data has been created.  I cannot drop the table;  the table maybe partly populated and I cannot overwrite existing data.  This is the root of my problem.  Because of the 'Were' the query is very slow.

The query I am using to populate the table is:

```
   DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20000101'
     ,@EndDate DATE = '21631231';

   WITH    N10(n)
           AS (SELECT    1
              FROM      ( VALUES ( 0), ( 1), ( 2), ( 3), ( 4), ( 5), ( 6), ( 7), ( 8), ( 9) ) v (n)),
         N100(n)
           AS (SELECT    1
              FROM      N10
                     ,N10 n),
         N10000(n)
           AS (SELECT    1
              FROM      N100
                     ,N100 n),
         N100000(n)
           AS (SELECT    1
              FROM      N10
                     ,N10000 n),
         N AS (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate) + 1)
                      n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
              FROM      N100000)
      INSERT  INTO [dbo].[BusinessCalendarDetails2] (BusinessDate,CreatedById,CreatedTime,BusinessCalendarId,IsWeekday,
                                            IsHoliday)
      (SELECT InsertDate,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,1,0
       FROM   N
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD (DAY,n,@StartDate)) d (InsertDate)
       WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM  [BusinessCalendarDetails2]
                       WHERE  [BusinessDate] = InsertDate ));
```

This works but the problem is the 'WHERE' to identify if the date already exists in the table is severely slowing it down (14 mins).  So I am wondering if someone has a faster solution for identifying already existing dates?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

The following is the entire script, it works fairly well; others may find it useful.

```
    -- Populate table with business holidays 

    -- If the table is missing add it
    IF OBJECT_ID('BusinessCalendarDetails2') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 (
                Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
                          NOT NULL
               ,BusinessDate [DATE] NOT NULL
               ,Day AS DAY(BusinessDate)
               ,Week AS DATEPART(WEEK,BusinessDate)
               ,[Month] AS MONTH(BusinessDate)
               ,Quarter AS DATEPART(QUARTER,BusinessDate)
               ,[Year] AS YEAR(BusinessDate)
               ,DayOfWeek AS DATEPART(WEEKDAY,BusinessDate)
               ,CreatedById BIGINT NOT NULL
               ,CreatedTime DATETIMEOFFSET(7) NOT NULL
               ,UpdatedById BIGINT NULL
               ,UpdatedTime DATETIMEOFFSET(7) NULL
               ,BusinessCalendarId BIGINT NOT NULL
               ,RowVersion TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
               ,IsWeekday BIT NOT NULL
               ,IsHoliday BIT NOT NULL
               ,Description NVARCHAR(50)
               ,PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY])
            ON  [PRIMARY];
        END;

    -- Check if this col exists, 
    IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2','Day') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
            ADD   -- Add calculated fields
            Day AS DAY(BusinessDate), Week AS DATEPART(WEEK, BusinessDate), [Month] AS MONTH(BusinessDate), Quarter AS DATEPART(QUARTER, BusinessDate), [Year] AS YEAR(BusinessDate), DayOfWeek AS DATEPART(WEEKDAY, BusinessDate);
        END;
    GO

    -- Date range to populate
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE= '20000101' ,@EndDate DATE= '21631231';
    WITH    N10(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      ( VALUES ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ), ( 8 ), ( 9 ) ) AS v (n)),
            N100(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      N10
                           ,N10 AS n),
            N10000(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      N100
                           ,N100 AS n),
            N100000(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      N10
                           ,N10000 AS n),
            N AS (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate) + 1)
                            n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
                  FROM      N100000)
        INSERT  INTO dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 (BusinessDate,CreatedById,CreatedTime,BusinessCalendarId,IsWeekday,
                                                   IsHoliday)
        (SELECT InsertDate,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,1,0
         FROM   N
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD (DAY,n,@StartDate)) AS d (InsertDate)
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM   BusinessCalendarDetails2
                             WHERE  BusinessDate = InsertDate ));

    -- Set Descriptions
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     Description = DATENAME(dw,BusinessDate)
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2;

    -- Set weekdays
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsWeekday = 0,Description = Description + ' Weekend'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 AS c1
    WHERE   DATEPART(WEEKDAY,c1.BusinessDate) IN (1,7);

    -- New Years Day
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' New Years Day'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    WHERE   BusinessCalendarDetails2.[Month] = 1
            AND (SELECT CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(DW,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-01-01')) % 7
                          WHEN 0 THEN 3 -- SAT
                          WHEN 1 THEN 2 -- Sunday
                          ELSE 1
                        END) = BusinessCalendarDetails2.Day;

    -- Family Day Day -- 3rd Monday in February 
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Family Day'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 2
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 15 AND 21;

    -- Canada Day
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Canada Day'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    WHERE   BusinessCalendarDetails2.[Month] = 7
            AND (SELECT CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(DW,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-07-01')) % 7
                          WHEN 0 THEN 3 -- SAT
                          WHEN 1 THEN 2 -- Sunday
                          ELSE 1
                        END) = BusinessCalendarDetails2.Day;

    -- Civic Holiday
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Civic Holiday'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 8
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 1 AND 7;


    -- Good Friday
    UPDATE  BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Good Friday'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 AS dimdate
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT dimdate.Year AS y) _y
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y / 100 AS c,y - 19 * y / 19 AS n) _nc
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT (c - 17) / 25 AS k) _k
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c - c / 4 - (c - k) / 3 + 19 * n + 15 AS i1) _i1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i1 - 30 * i1 / 30 AS i2) _i2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i2 - (i2 / 28) * (1 - (i2 / 28) * 29 / (i2 + 1) * (21 - n) / 11) AS i) _i
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y + y / 4 + i + 2 - c + c / 4 AS j1) _j1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT j1 - 7 * j1 / 7 AS j) _j
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i - j AS el) _el
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT 3 + (el + 40) / 44 AS m) _m
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT el + 28 - 31 * m / 4 AS d) _d
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (y,m,d) AS EasterSunday) _Easter
    WHERE   dimdate.BusinessDate = DATEADD(DAY,-2,EasterSunday);


    -- Easter Sunday
    UPDATE  BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 0,Description = Description + ' Easter Sunday'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 AS dimdate
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT dimdate.Year AS y) _y
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y / 100 AS c,y - 19 * y / 19 AS n) _nc
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT (c - 17) / 25 AS k) _k
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c - c / 4 - (c - k) / 3 + 19 * n + 15 AS i1) _i1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i1 - 30 * i1 / 30 AS i2) _i2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i2 - (i2 / 28) * (1 - (i2 / 28) * 29 / (i2 + 1) * (21 - n) / 11) AS i) _i
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y + y / 4 + i + 2 - c + c / 4 AS j1) _j1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT j1 - 7 * j1 / 7 AS j) _j
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i - j AS el) _el
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT 3 + (el + 40) / 44 AS m) _m
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT el + 28 - 31 * m / 4 AS d) _d
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (y,m,d) AS EasterSunday) _Easter
    WHERE   dimdate.BusinessDate = EasterSunday;


    -- Labour Day  --  first Monday of September  
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Labour Day'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 9
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 1 AND 7;

    -- Set Thanksgiving
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Thanksgiving'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 10
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 8 AND 14;

    ---- Christmas
    UPDATE  dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Christmas Holidays'
    FROM    dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2
    WHERE   [Month] = 12
            AND Day BETWEEN 26 AND 28
            AND (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-12-25') IN (1,7)     -- Is Christmas on a weekend this year
                 OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-12-26') IN (1,7))     -- Is Boxingday on a weekend this year
            AND DATEPART(dw,BusinessDate) <> 4 -- NOT ON Wednesday!
            AND DATEPART(DAY,(SELECT    CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw,BusinessDate)) % 7
                                          WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(DAY,2,BusinessDate) -- Saturday
                                          WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,BusinessDate) -- Sunday
                                          ELSE BusinessDate
                                        END AS Weekday)) BETWEEN 26
                                                         AND     28
            OR [Month] = 12    -- Is christmas a week day?
            AND Day BETWEEN 25 AND 26
            AND IsWeekday = 1;
    GO

    -- Return table to orig state
    ALTER TABLE dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails2 DROP COLUMN Day, Week, [Month], Quarter, [Year], DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Why don't you make [BusinessDate] as unique

Comment: That's a good idea but I cannot change the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no index on BusinessDate and the table is big enough, that would certainly slow things down. If it is indexed, you may need to rebuild/reorganize it, or even just redo the statistics.

Otherwise, depending on your disks, it may be quicker to insert the distinct BusinessDate column values into a temp table with an index on it and compare against that.

It could be many things. If you haven't already, you should look at the ACTUAL execution plan and statistics for your query to get a better idea of what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: This is a good idea!!  I switched it to use a Temp table then insert the miss matches...  Runtime = 8 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final answer using a Temp table it runs much faster

```
 -- Populate table with business holidays 

    CREATE TABLE #BusCalDet (
        Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
                  NOT NULL
       ,BusinessDate [DATE] NOT NULL
       ,Day AS DAY(BusinessDate)
       ,Week AS DATEPART(WEEK,BusinessDate)
       ,[Month] AS MONTH(BusinessDate)
       ,Quarter AS DATEPART(QUARTER,BusinessDate)
       ,[Year] AS YEAR(BusinessDate)
       ,DayOfWeek AS DATEPART(WEEKDAY,BusinessDate)
       ,CreatedById BIGINT NOT NULL
       ,CreatedTime DATETIMEOFFSET(7) NOT NULL
       ,UpdatedById BIGINT NULL
       ,UpdatedTime DATETIMEOFFSET(7) NULL
       ,BusinessCalendarId BIGINT NOT NULL
       ,RowVersion TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
       ,IsWeekday BIT NOT NULL
       ,IsHoliday BIT NOT NULL
       ,Description NVARCHAR(50)
       ,PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY])
    ON  [PRIMARY];


    -- Date range to populate
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE= '20000101'
       ,@EndDate DATE= '21631231';
    WITH    N10(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      ( VALUES ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 ), ( 5 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ), ( 8 ), ( 9 ) ) AS v (n)),
            N100(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      N10
                           ,N10 AS n),
            N10000(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      N100
                           ,N100 AS n),
            N100000(n)
              AS (SELECT    1
                  FROM      N10
                           ,N10000 AS n),
            N AS (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate) + 1)
                            n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
                  FROM      N100000)
        INSERT  INTO #BusCalDet (BusinessDate,CreatedById,CreatedTime,BusinessCalendarId,IsWeekday,IsHoliday)
        SELECT  InsertDate,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,1,0
        FROM    N
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD (DAY,n,@StartDate)) AS d (InsertDate);


    -- Set Descriptions
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     Description = DATENAME(dw,BusinessDate)
    FROM    #BusCalDet;

    -- Set weekdays
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsWeekday = 0,Description = Description + ' Weekend'
    FROM    #BusCalDet AS c1
    WHERE   DATEPART(WEEKDAY,c1.BusinessDate) IN (1,7);

    -- New Years Day
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' New Years Day'
    FROM    #BusCalDet
    WHERE   #BusCalDet.[Month] = 1
            AND (SELECT CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(DW,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-01-01'))
                          % 7
                          WHEN 0 THEN 3 -- SAT
                          WHEN 1 THEN 2 -- Sunday
                          ELSE 1
                        END) = #BusCalDet.Day;

    -- Family Day Day -- 3rd Monday in February 
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Family Day'
    FROM    #BusCalDet AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 2
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 15 AND 21;

    -- Canada Day
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Canada Day'
    FROM    #BusCalDet
    WHERE   #BusCalDet.[Month] = 7
            AND (SELECT CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(DW,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-07-01'))
                          % 7
                          WHEN 0 THEN 3 -- SAT
                          WHEN 1 THEN 2 -- Sunday
                          ELSE 1
                        END) = #BusCalDet.Day;

    -- Civic Holiday
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Civic Holiday'
    FROM    #BusCalDet AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 8
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 1 AND 7;


    -- Good Friday
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Good Friday'
    FROM    #BusCalDet AS dimdate
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT dimdate.Year AS y) _y
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y / 100 AS c,y - 19 * y / 19 AS n) _nc
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT (c - 17) / 25 AS k) _k
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c - c / 4 - (c - k) / 3 + 19 * n + 15 AS i1) _i1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i1 - 30 * i1 / 30 AS i2) _i2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i2 - (i2 / 28) * (1 - (i2 / 28) * 29 / (i2 + 1) * (21 - n) / 11) AS i) _i
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y + y / 4 + i + 2 - c + c / 4 AS j1) _j1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT j1 - 7 * j1 / 7 AS j) _j
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i - j AS el) _el
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT 3 + (el + 40) / 44 AS m) _m
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT el + 28 - 31 * m / 4 AS d) _d
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (y,m,d) AS EasterSunday) _Easter
    WHERE   dimdate.BusinessDate = DATEADD(DAY,-2,EasterSunday);


    -- Easter Sunday
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 0,Description = Description + ' Easter Sunday'
    FROM    #BusCalDet AS dimdate
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT dimdate.Year AS y) _y
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y / 100 AS c,y - 19 * y / 19 AS n) _nc
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT (c - 17) / 25 AS k) _k
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c - c / 4 - (c - k) / 3 + 19 * n + 15 AS i1) _i1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i1 - 30 * i1 / 30 AS i2) _i2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i2 - (i2 / 28) * (1 - (i2 / 28) * 29 / (i2 + 1) * (21 - n) / 11) AS i) _i
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT y + y / 4 + i + 2 - c + c / 4 AS j1) _j1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT j1 - 7 * j1 / 7 AS j) _j
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i - j AS el) _el
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT 3 + (el + 40) / 44 AS m) _m
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT el + 28 - 31 * m / 4 AS d) _d
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (y,m,d) AS EasterSunday) _Easter
    WHERE   dimdate.BusinessDate = EasterSunday;


    -- Labour Day  --  first Monday of September  
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Labour Day'
    FROM    #BusCalDet AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 9
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 1 AND 7;

    -- Set Thanksgiving
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Thanksgiving'
    FROM    #BusCalDet AS c1
    WHERE   c1.[Month] = 10
            AND c1.DayOfWeek = 2
            AND c1.Day BETWEEN 8 AND 14;

    ---- Christmas
    UPDATE  #BusCalDet
    SET     IsHoliday = 1,Description = Description + ' Christmas Holidays'
    FROM    #BusCalDet
    WHERE   [Month] = 12
            AND Day BETWEEN 26 AND 28
            AND (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-12-25') IN (1,7)     -- Is Christmas on a weekend this year
                 OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,BusinessDate) AS VARCHAR) + '-12-26') IN (1,7))     -- Is Boxingday on a weekend this year
            AND DATEPART(dw,BusinessDate) <> 4 -- NOT ON Wednesday!
            AND DATEPART(DAY,(SELECT    CASE (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(dw,BusinessDate)) % 7
                                          WHEN 0 THEN DATEADD(DAY,2,BusinessDate) -- Saturday
                                          WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,BusinessDate) -- Sunday
                                          ELSE BusinessDate
                                        END AS Weekday)) BETWEEN 26
                                                         AND     28
            OR [Month] = 12    -- Is christmas a week day?
            AND Day BETWEEN 25 AND 26
            AND IsWeekday = 1;

    -- Match orig table Schema
    ALTER TABLE #BusCalDet DROP COLUMN Day, Week, [Month], Quarter, [Year], DayOfWeek;

      -- Insert in to the main table'
    INSERT  INTO dbo.BusinessCalendarDetails (BusinessDate,CreatedById,CreatedTime,BusinessCalendarId,IsWeekday,
                                              IsHoliday,[Description])
        -- Find Rows that are missing
    SELECT  DT.BusinessDate,DT.CreatedById,DT.CreatedTime,DT.BusinessCalendarId,DT.IsWeekday,DT.IsHoliday,
            DT.[Description]
    FROM    #BusCalDet DT
    LEFT JOIN BusinessCalendarDetails ON BusinessCalendarDetails.BusinessDate = DT.BusinessDate
    WHERE   BusinessCalendarDetails.Id IS NULL
    ORDER BY DT.BusinessDate;-- id
```